# How can i count a column in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app to show a column from another table but i want to know how to count the results instead of showing information

Here my tables

```
|policies|
 |id|  |num_policy|
   1       11111
   2       22222

|insurances|
 |id|  |id_policy| |net_insurance|
  1        1          33333
  2        1          44444  
  3        2          55555
  4        2          66666  

|insurance_financing|       
  |id| |id_ensurance| |number|
   1       1            1544
   2       2             858
   3       3            8484  
   4       4             848
```

I'm trying to do

```
|num_policy|    |count| 
     11111       2
     22222       2
```

This is my controller

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print
      @policies= Policy.find(:all)
    end
end
```

This is my model

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurances
end

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :policy
  has_many :insurance_financing_details
end

class InsuranceFinancingDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :insurance
end
```

This is my view

```
 <% @policies.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.num_policy   %>

    <%  p.insurances.each do |insurance| %>
       <% insurance.insurance_financing_details.each do |detail| %>
          <%= detail.number %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Please somebody can help me with this problem

I will really appreciate help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Policies.joins(:insurances).group("policies.id").count` will give you a hash where the key is the policies.id and the value is the count of the insurances for each policy.

NOTE: if a policy does not have any insurances, it will not be included in the result.

Comment: but your code is for rails 3 and i tagged rails 2, how can i do this?

Comment: Didn't notice the Rails 2 tag.  Maybe something like this: `Insurance.count(:group=>"insurances.policy_id")`

Comment: i got undefined method `num_policy' for [1, 2]:Array

Comment: That makes no sense.  Are your table definitions above correct?  `id_policy` is the FK in insurances back to policies?  I don't think it is; otherwise you would need to setup some custom FK directives on your associations.